# Codeception add new JsonTypes

Tags: testing, codeception, web-api-testing

I wonder if it's possible to define some custom `JsonType` for validation API responses through `seeResponseMatchesJsonType` method. I mean, let's suppose I have response with a structure:

```
[
   'id' => 'integer',
   'name' => 'string',
   'address' => [
      'street' => 'string',
      'city' => 'string'
   ]
]
```

Obviously this structure has complex type `address` embedded and in the whole app such type might be used several times so I would like to write simply:

```
$I->seeResponseMatchesJsonType([
   'id' => 'integer',
   'name' => 'string',
   'address' => 'addressType'
]);
```

Without rewriting this embedded structure all the time. How can I achieve it in Codeception?

Comment: It is currently impossible, how about using variable instead?
Make it a static property of helper class if you want to access it from different tests.

Comment: I already did use constants in helpers but wanted to ask if such feature is available. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by using method addCustomFilter from \Codeception\Util\JsonType class.

````
/**
     * Adds custom filter to JsonType list.
     * You should specify a name and parameters of a filter.
     *
     * Example:
     *
     * ```php
     * <?php
     * JsonType::addCustomFilter('email', function($value) {
     *     return strpos('@', $value) !== false;
     * });
     * // => use it as 'string:email'

     *
     * // add custom function to matcher with `len($val)` syntax
     * // parameter matching patterns should be valid regex and start with `/` char
     * JsonType::addCustomFilter('/len\((.*?)\)/', function($value, $len) {
     *   return strlen($value) == $len;
     * });
     * // use it as 'string:len(5)'
     * ?>
     * ```
     *
     * @param $name
     * @param callable $callable
     */
    public static function addCustomFilter($name, callable $callable)
    {
        static::$customFilters[$name] = $callable;
    }
````